# Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 with flex sdk for making JW player

Tags: xml, apache-flex, ant, jwplayer, adobe-flash-cs3

I'm making JW player. I have installed Adobe Flash Builder.
When I try to parse the XML file of JW player with ANT, ANT is not parsing my XML file completely and throws an exception.

Here is screen what I'm getting in exception http://prntscr.com/6gmde9
and this is my build properties file.

```
flexsdk = C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/sdks/4.6.0

execextension = .exe

flexsdk.target = 11.4

application.package = com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/player

application.class = Player

application.majorversion = 6

application.minorversion = 12
```

Any thoughts what I'm missing here?

Comment: Do you have Java and Python installed?